# Repeated k-fold CV loop in R to capture metrics

Tags: r, loops, cross-validation

I'm relatively new to R, and as an exercise I'm looking to run k-fold CV 50 times in a loop. The error I am getting is *"number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"*

```
knn.preds <- lapply(folds, function(f) knn(train = X[-f,-61],
                                           test = X[f,-61],
                                           cl = X$Class[-f],
                                           k = 5))
obs <- lapply(folds, function(x) X$Class[x])

set.seed(5)
m = 50
multiACC = c()
multiSENS = c()
multiSPEC = c()
multiF1 = c()

for(i in 1:m) {   folds <- createFolds(X$Class, k = 10)
                knn.metrics <- mapply(function(pred, obs) FUN = confusionMatrix(data = pred, reference = obs, mode = "everything"),
                      pred = knn.preds, obs = obs,
                      SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

                knn.accuracy <- vapply(knn.metrics, function(cm) cm[["overall"]]["Accuracy"], numeric(1)) 
                knn.sensitivity <- vapply(knn.metrics, function(cm) cm[["byClass"]]["Sensitivity"], numeric(1)) 
                knn.specificity <- vapply(knn.metrics, function(cm) cm[["byClass"]]["Specificity"], numeric(1))
                knn.F1 <- vapply(knn.metrics, function(cm) cm[["byClass"]]["F1"], numeric(1))

                multiACC[i] = knn.accuracy
                multiSENS[i] = knn.sensitivity
                multiSPEC[i] = knn.specificity
                multiF1[i] = knn.F1
}
```

the idea being to plot multiACC etc... in boxplots at the end. But I have that length error in the mapply and unsure where I'm going wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide us with a sample of your data (we can't run the current code because we don't have `folds`).  You can use `dput()` to get your data out of R.  Additionally, you should do the work to figure out which line is causing the error.  Without these additions, I will vote to close this question as not specific enough to meet SO guidelines.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do have folds in the loop..... folds <- createFolds(X$Class, k = 10). Also the data is the Sonar data in mlbench (X = Sonar).  The error is flagged at *knn.metrics <- mapply* and I think it's got a problem with how it then deploys beyond that to the subsequent variables. I gues my question is, is it valid to use *knn.accuracy <- vapply(knn.metrics, function(cm) cm[["overall"]]["Accuracy"], numeric(1)) * and then *multiACC[i] = knn.accuracy*?

Comment: I suggest deleting this question and re-posting where you specify `folds <- Sonar` from package `mlbench` and stating your specific questions (as you have done in the prior comment).  That way, more folks than just me will see it and you're likely to get help sooner.